# What's the __vmware__ user in the group policy

Tags: windows, vmware, vmware-workstation, group-policy

VMWare workstation added a **vmware** user in the group policy:

Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Allow log on locally

[image]

What's the purpose of this **vmware** user?
Can it be deleted without affecting the VMWare workstation?
Is it a backdoor account of VMWare workstation for remote login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see:   [__vmare__user](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Virtualization-Technology/vmware-user-questions/td-p/1645909)

It is for a headless VM.

> The user's security credentials are used as part of the mechanism to
> reconnect to a headless VM; to connect, you either have to be
> Administrator or you have to talk to the Authorization service which
> does have the credentials and can open a connection on your behalf.

__vmware__user does no harm and I suggest you do not delete it. I have had VMware running for many years.